# CKEditor PlugIn, Simple PlugIn Ability

Tags: ckeditor

I'm interested in creating a plugin that does this simple task:
Steps
1. User selects some text by highlighting
2. user clicks the plug-in
3. CKEDITOR, wraps the selected text with a  tag with some class and/or ID.

Can anyone help with this? I've been playing with CKEDITOR.htmlWriter but haven't even been able to get that started: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.htmlWriter.html#constructor

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the basicstyles plugin, you just need to define a button that applies a "style", and you define what's the element, attributes and styles that this "style" means.

Comment: There is nothing helpful here?

Comment: I understand, you don't want someone to help you, but someone to write the code for you. Well, I have other things to do.